# Collection not Created in Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented a code to create a collection named "Users". the code is running properly but is not saving my data in the database of my console.

Here is my code

```
user_profile.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> uploadtask) {
         String download_url = uploadtask.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

         if (uploadtask.isSuccessful()){
             Map<String,Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
             userMap.put("name",user);
             userMap.put("image",download_url);
             firebaseFirestore.collection("Users")
                              .document(user_id).set(userMap)
                              .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                       Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                       SendToMain();
                                       progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                   }
                              });
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "error: "+uploadtask.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
      }
});
```

I don't know what's going wrong and what's causing the problem. please help me for this. I am new to firebase by the way.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, not getting any error

Comment: Have you tried to `addOnFailureListener` and log the exception? What does it return?

Comment: You may want to read about [why 'Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes It would be better to allow Firebase store to auto create meaningful documentID for you.

> can you try using add() function like below.

```
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").add(UserMap)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot written with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i need to store this data with uid. current code block is inside the firebase auth method where user registers as a new user in firebase

Comment: It seems unlikely the id is a problem. But I'd definitely add a `addOnFailureListener` to your code to log (preferably `Log.e`) any problems that Firestore reports back.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out everyone but it solved out of nowhere automatically. the thing was I just change the rules in the Firestore and it took 10 mins to make the changes that's why is was not storing my data. logically you all are right. thank you for helping